Camera Tracker Solve Failed: Not Enough Tracks – How to Fix This?
I’m working in Fusion and trying to use the Camera Tracker node to track a video clip, but I keep getting the following error:
Solve failed: not enough tracks
Mathematically, there must be at least 8 tracks in common between consecutive frames to reconstruct the camera motion. In practice, you want a lot more than 8 (typically 150-ish) for a robust and accurate solution. You requested to solve the range [7.0, 1000.0] and there were only 2 tracks in common between frames 7.0 and 8.0.
How to Fix This?

Project file: https://drive.google.com/file/d/1POmNLC9GcdCr4xIF2d-Tx7AQ5Po4MjF2/view?usp=sharing

Video: https://drive.google.com/file/d/1fTjZ-usMRomV53JJqZ-Cu434hnvTRE6y/view?usp=sharing


Increase the number of tracks: In general, you need a higher number of tracks to get an accurate camera solve. Ensure that the scene has enough distinguishable features or points that can be tracked over time. Here are a few tips:
•   Improve contrast: If the video is too flat or low-contrast, it may be difficult for the tracker to identify enough points. Try adjusting the contrast of the clip using color grading or pre-processing.
•   Increase the tracking range: The user might be tracking over too few frames, or the range could be too short. Extending the range can help, but this will also require more points to track accurately.
•   Check the settings in the Camera Tracker: Make sure that the tracking settings are set to find and use more tracks. In some cases, setting a higher threshold for track detection can help.

Manually add more tracking points: If the automatic tracker can’t find enough features, try manually adding some points to the scene, especially in areas with high detail or contrast.

Use a different tracker: If the Camera Tracker is still not working, try using other tracking nodes like the Point Tracker in Fusion, which can sometimes be more flexible in tracking different scenes.

Check the footage quality: Low resolution or blurry footage may hinder tracking accuracy. If possible, use higher quality or more stable footage for better tracking results.

Check for motion blur: If there’s a lot of motion blur, it may be difficult for the tracker to distinguish points between frames. You might need to use a footage that has less blur or consider a motion blur reduction technique.

Improve the feature distribution: The footage may have insufficient feature points spread across the scene. In this case, you can adjust the settings to search for features more widely across the frame.

Try manual keyframing: As a last resort, if automatic tracking is failing, manual keyframing of camera motion could be used.





How can I change from which to which point the video should be tracked
